# Error of start with multiple data regions

Tags: java, ignite

I got a ignite active error when i start my ignite server node with configuration below:

```
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setConsistentId("test");
    cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("oneDataGrid");
    cfg.setClientMode(false);

    DataStorageConfiguration dc = new DataStorageConfiguration();
    dc.setWalMode(WALMode.DEFAULT);
    // enabling persistent
    DataRegionConfiguration drc1 = new DataRegionConfiguration();
    drc1.setName("disk");
    drc1.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    drc1.setSwapPath("disktest");
    // disabling persistent
    DataRegionConfiguration drc2 = new DataRegionConfiguration();
    drc2.setName("memory");
    // Setting initial RAM size.
    drc2.setInitialSize(100L * 1024 * 1024);
    // Setting maximum RAM size.
    drc2.setMaxSize(500L * 1024 * 1024);
    drc2.setPersistenceEnabled(false);
    drc2.setSwapPath("memorytest");
    dc.setDataRegionConfigurations(drc1,drc2);
    cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dc);
    // node find
    TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
    List<String> ips = new ArrayList<>();
    ips.add("127.0.0.1:47500..47503");
    ipFinder.setAddresses(ips);
    spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
    // Starting the node.
    Ignite ignite =  Ignition.start(cfg);
    ignite.active(true);
    this.server = ignite;
```

and the error is:

```
    org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find cache group descriptor [grpId=812588779]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.getPageMemoryForCacheGroup(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1598)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.restoreMemory(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1540)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.readCheckpointAndRestoreMemory(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:568)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onClusterStateChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:814)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:583)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2279)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It should be noted that the error appears alternately, which means I start it successfully at first time, and fail at second time, and then start it successfully at third time, then fail at the fourth time ......

the version of ignite I used is V2.3.0

Comment: It should be noted that I configured two different data regions in one DataStorage in which one is persistence enabled and the other is persistence disabled

Comment: It can happen, if names of your caches contain slashes. Is it your case?